# How to detect overlapping communities using snap BIGCLAM method?

Tags: social-networking, snappy

I want to detect overlapping communities in a network. I have file trust.txt whose format is like this- [user-id (trustor), user-id (trustee)]. I want to run snap BIGCLAM algorithm for community detection. How I can run snap BIGCLAM method to get the output as a community. I saw this link https://github.com/snap-stanford/snap/tree/master/examples/bigclam but how I can compile and run this code to get the output.

Answer (score 0):

This answer might be too late for you. Nevertheless, it might be helpful to others.

Once you download the whole snap-master, you need to perform make all, as stated there. This installs advanced features and the examples.

Then you can switch to the directory bigclam within examples and run make there. After that, you can run ./bigclam (on Linux), as stated in the Readme file.

Basically, you put there your prepared data (edge list with node indices; if your nodes have names, also that file is needed). You run it as per the Readme example.

./bigclam -o:'your_out_prefix' -i:'your_nodeids.edgelist' -c:1000